# how to divide pdf into shall chunks (many pieces per page)?

Tags: pdf

I have a pdf file and I need to get get small pieces of data from it. 
It is structured like this :

> Page1:
>
> Question 1
>
> ......................................
>
> ......................................
>
> Question 2
>
> ......................................
>
> ......................................
>
> Page End

I want to get Question 1 and Question 2 as separate html files, which contain text and image.

I've tried

`pdftohtml -c pdffile.pdf output.html`

And I got files with png images, but how to do I cut the Image into smaller chunks to fit the size of each Question (I want to separate each question into individual files)?

Answer (score 0):

There's a (commercial) application called *A-PDF split", which helps you to split the content manually as per your requirement.

Comment: I have 129 pdf files, so i'd like to automate the process.